# Specifying two providers for the same block in a Vagrantfile

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vmware

In my Vagrantfile I have configs for Virtualbox and for VMware. As the VMware providers for Windows/Linux and Mac have different names (vmware_workstation, vmware_fusion), but use the same downloaded box, I find myself speifying the same config twice.

```
config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v, override|
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "1024"
    v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "1"
end

config.vm.provider "vmware_workstation" do |v, override|
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "1024"
    v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "1"
end
```

What is the syntax for allowing me to combine these two into a single block, something like:

```
config.vm.provider in ["vmware_fusion", "vmware_workstation"] do |v, override|
   v.vmx["memsize"] = "1024"
   v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "1"
end
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
["vmware_fusion", "vmware_workstation"].each do |vmware_provider|
  config.vm.provider vmware_provider do |v, override|
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "1024"
    v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "1"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you [are restricted to one provider per machine (bottom of the page)](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/basic_usage.html), though in a multimachine environment you can specify a provider per machine

So maybe you could do something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  machines = [
    { name: "machine1_fusion", provider: "vmware_fusion" },
    { name: "machine1_workstation", provider: "vmware_workstation" }
  ]

  machines.each do |machine|
    config.vm.define machine[:name] do |m|
      ... #box config etc
      m.vm.provider machine[:provider] do |p|
        p.vmx["memsize"] = "1024"
        p.vmx["numvcpus"] = "1"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's just one VM running, but depending on whether I'm on my Windows machine or my Mac will determine whether the provider for the VM is Fusion or Workstation. In reality, they use the exact same box but as the Vagrantfile refers to the provider by a different name in each case, I need to specify the same config twice.  I should be able to take the syntax from your example though and solve my problem.